# Mockito+PowerMock gradle configuration

Tags: android, gradle, mockito, build.gradle, powermock

I need to use in my android instrumented tests `mockito` and `powermock`.

The main problem is that both of them have some problems with configuring it in `gradle` because of conflicts and other stuff.

Maybe somebody who has working configuration of `.gradle` file for `mockito+powermock` in `android` instrumented tests could share it?

Answer (score 4):

This is my gradle configuration to use mockito and powerMock:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    /**Power mock**/
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.3"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.3"
    /**End of power mock **/


}
```

NOTE: I had to remove the mockito dependency in order to make it works:

```
//Remove this line
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the configuration I am using and it's working perfectly fine.
after 1.7.0 powermock-api-mockito change to powermock-api-mockito2

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'

testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.7"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.7"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.7"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.6"
```